# Есть ли константы в Shell/Bash?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

Есть ли способ в *POSIX Shell* и *Bash* сделать переменную
константой?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да.  Используйте ключевое слово `readonly`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

readonly x=42

x=100500 # Ошибка: x: is read only

unset x # Ошибка: x: is read only
```

Это работает и в *Bash*.

Документация в стандарте:
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#readonly.